# what is the correct design for ER mapping for this situation?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to model this problem :

> One faculty may supervise several students or not. One student has at
>   least one, at most two supervisors.

I'm looking for actual Relational table design on how to do this.

Comment: And what have you tried so far and why don't you think it is correct?

Comment: Right now my design looks like this : one supervise [supervise_id, faculty_id, student_id]; supervise_id is pk which is not null. there is a check condition like so SELECT COUNT(*) FROM supervise GROUP BY student_id HAVING count(*) < 2... I have not created anything on the DB as of now. Need to be sure the commands are correct before I execute them. But I feel this design of creating a supervise table does not satisfy the given requirements. Am I wrong Mr. @EWit ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (somewhat bold) way to model this is

- a STUDENT table
- a FACULTY table

Now give STUDENT columns FACULTY1 and FACULTY2. Both are foreign keys to FACULTY. Constrain FACULTY1  with NOT_NULL. This enforces that a student has at least one FACULTY. FACULTY2 can be null, but it still a foreign key.

FACULTY somehow does not know anything about STUDENT. When no STUDENT references a FACULTY it has no students and any number of Students can reference faculty.

This model has a number of drawbacks (I said it is bold):

- A STUDENT being supervised by only one FACULTY must have this set in FACULTY1 (not FACULTY2). Likewise when a student who was supervised by 2 FACULTIES deletes one of them, you can only delete FACULTY2 or you must first swap the fields. You can circumvent this by a more clever constraint (FACULTY1 is not null or FFACULTY2 is not null)
- If you ever want to change the design, so a STUDENT can have 3 FACULTIES you need to add columns to STUDENT. This however, is not as bad as it may sound.

On the pro side, there is nothing but referential integrity and NOT NULL involved in this design.